# Moralis.Cloud.beforeSave not triggered when adding tables through a sync job (plugin)

Tags: web3js, javascript, nodes, polygon

I ran into this a while back and it was doing my head in.

Could it be that a ‘Moralis.Cloud.beforeSave’ in Cloud Functions is not triggered when adding tables through a sync job (plugin)?

When I run the beforeSave just using the web3 UI it works.
When I delete all the tables and manually run the Sync job to create new tables, beforeSave did not run to add the additional user and token fields:

```
// link sale and item data Polygon
Moralis.Cloud.beforeSave("ItemsForSalePolygon", async (request) => {
  const query = new Moralis.Query("PolygonNFTOwners")
  query.equalTo("token_address", request.object.get('tokenAddress'))
  query.equalTo("token_id", request.object.get('tokenId'))
  const object = await query.first()
  if (object){
      const owner = object.attributes.owner_of
    const userQuery = new Moralis.Query(Moralis.User)
      userQuery.equalTo("accounts", owner)
    const userObject = await userQuery.first({useMasterKey:true})
    if (userObject){
        request.object.set('user', userObject);
    }
    request.object.set('token', object);
  }
})
```

Or is the sync job cached somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For performance reasons, the historical sync uses bulk insert. A side effect of this optimization is that triggers are not fired for those inserts. This explains the behaviour you observed where the triggers fire on real-time inserts but not when syncing historical data.

You can create a [Jobs](https://docs.moralis.io/jobs) or cloud function and run it manually to take care of any initialization that needs to occur after the initial historical sync